# Contains table not working

Tags: sql-server

I have a full text on a Column Called SearchTerm in a table called Lease.

I tried doing something like:-

```
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(Lease, SearchTerm, 'Canterbury*')
```

No Records are returned. I do see a record with a SearchTerm equal to - '3 Canterbury Green||Imaging Technology Group'. Yet the record doesn't show up. Can anyone tell me what is going on.

Comment: Did you full text index the `SearchTerm` column?

Comment: According to [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142492(v=sql.105).aspx) the search term needs to be in double quotes in the single quotes for the prefix search to be recognised as such.

Comment: Try this - `SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(Lease, SearchTerm, '*Canterbury*')`

Answer (score 0):

> It performs a SQL Server full-text search on `full-text indexed columns`
>   containing character-based data types.

[CONTAINSTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql)

```
CREATE TABLE Flags (Country nvarchar(30) NOT NULL, FlagColors varchar(200));  
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX FlagKey ON Flags(Country);  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('France', 'Blue and White and Red');  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('Italy', 'Green and White and Red');  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('Tanzania', 'Green and Yellow and Black and Yellow and Blue');  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('US', '3 Canterbury Green||Imaging Technology Group');  
SELECT * FROM Flags;  
GO  

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG TestFTCat;  
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Flags(FlagColors) KEY INDEX FlagKey ON TestFTCat;  
GO   

SELECT * FROM Flags;  
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, 'Canterbury')
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, '"Canterbury*"')
```

You may have to enclose the `'"Canterbury*"'` in double quotes as @Richard specified.

It's not necessary to specify the `*` though as you see the above select gives same results.